# How to add row in a MIB table with snmpset?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib

I changed recently my custom MIB file to include tables and not only scalars, it validates, I can create sub-agent etc. but if I try to read it, it says no entries:

```
snmptable -v1 -c public hostname:10161 myMibName::myTable
myMibName::myTable: No entries
```

Well, I didn't add any default/sample rows to that table in my agent code.

If I try to set some values of the table with snmpset similar to how I did it on scalars, it always fails so table requires its own syntax.

How can I add a row to a table with snmpset or similar?

For example, sample table could look as simple as this one, where 'myString' is index:

```
MyTableEntrySequence::= SEQUENCE {
myString
OCTET STRING,
test1
Integer32,
test2
Integer32
```

}

EDIT: I didn't used RowStatus in my table. Am I required to use RowStatus to be able to add new rows?

EDIT2: I've compiled data_set.c agent from net-snmp samples, which populates a sample table with some data and can query its content with snmptable:

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public hostname:10161 netSnmpIETFWGTable
NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::nsIETFWGChair1."snmpv3" = STRING: "Russ Mundy"
NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::nsIETFWGChair2."snmpv3" = STRING: "David Harrington"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming, table (`myTable`) contains of a string (`stringIndex`) and 2 integers (`test1` and `test2`), whereas 1st table column is also table index, you can add rows with following:

`snmpset -v 1 -c public hostname:10161 yourMibName::test1.\"testString\" = 365`

This adds a new table row, where

```
stringIndex = "testString"
test1 = 365
test2 = 0
```

To set test2 to 42, you would need to call:

`snmpset -v 1 -c public hostname:10161 yourMibName::test2.\"testString\" = 42`

To verify your table content, you can use either snmpwalk or snmptable:

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public hostname:10161 yourMibName::myTable
```

Comment: I am using  snmpset supplied with net::snmp, this does not appear to accept the above syntax (= value) rather it takes (type value) and seems to need each column to be set separately. Which snmpset does this answer refer to?

Comment: netsnmp 5.7.3 on Linux, self compiled from sources. In my experience netsnmp on windows doesn't follow its own man pages and behaves in a strange not explainable way.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on a mac, using a Docker image that claims to have NET-SNMP version: 5.5 installed. Maybe I need to try a later version.