# SNMP4J : Is it possible to create an OID in the agent (server) MIB from the manager (client)?

Tags: frameworks, snmp, mib, snmp4j

I am using SNMP4J Framework and it implements and makes possible the standard SET, GET, GET-NEXT, etc. messages.

For example, with a SET, I can update the value of the MIB OID "1.3.6.1.2.50.0". This works perfectly for me. I can do that using [org.snmp4j.Snmp.set(PDU pdu, Target target)](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/Snmp.html#set(org.snmp4j.PDU,%20org.snmp4j.Target))

What I want to do now is to CREATE a custom MIB OID (as "1.3.6.1.2.100.0") FROM the client and assign a value to it and not simply update an existing MIB OID value.

Is there any standard SNMP way to do that easily ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

But it doesn't make sense in the context of SNMP to "create" a new scalar out of thin air; normally you are setting one already defined with a pre-defined OID, and that OID will usually be shared agent -> manager via a MIB file. Its OID will be the 0th instance (e.g., sysDescr.0).

You can however [add/remove rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756536/how-to-add-row-in-a-mib-table-with-snmpset) in a SNMP table (its rows and cells will have OIDs at instance 1, instance 2, etc.); and that SNMP table may have zero rows. The cells in the table can have values.

Here is some [background info on SNMP tables](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:snmptable).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @k1eran. Do you think it is possible to append a custom OID (determined by the manager) in an SNMP table ? For example, the table will be at OID "1.3.6.1.2.1" and I want to append an IP address to this OID "1.3.6.1.2.1.vvv.xxx.yyy.zzz", then increment a statistic linked to this IP address in another column of the row.

Comment: Yes, you can define a table where its rows have index of type = IpAddress  (see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1155) and other columns with whatever data, e.g. statistics, that  you need.

Comment: Do you have an idea which method can I use to add a row to the table ? I'm trying with PDU.addAll(VariableBinding[] vbs) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Look at MOTable  http://www.snmp4j.org/agent/doc/org/snmp4j/agent/mo/MOTable.html Also look at examples at http://www.jayway.com/2010/05/21/introduction-to-snmp4j/

Comment: Yes, I've looked. But I still can't see the link between the PDU.add method (which we always use from the client to make a SET) and the methods that add rows in the agent. Any help about making that link will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: _"its rows and cells will have OIDs at instance 0, instance 1, etc"_ Although valid, recommended best practice is to avoid that - have your table indexes start at 1 to avoid confusion. See §7.7 in RFC 2578.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you, good point. Answer updated.